# Geometric quantization of a hydrogen atom

Tags: specific-reference, quantization, hydrogen

I want to know how to quantize a hydrogen atom as an example of geometric quantization. Apparently there is a derivation in the book "Geometric Quantization in Action: Applications of Harmonic Analysis in Quantum Statistical Mechanics and Quantum Field Theory" by N.E. Hurt, but I have no access to it.

An article even paywalled or a book that easily accessible would suffice.

Comment: Google search involving "geometric quantization" and "kepler problem" should turn up something relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the answer comes also from extremely difficult to find sources. [image]

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you are interested only in the Energy levels, or more generally, also the eigenfunctions. For the energy levels, the integrality condition suffices. Recall, not every symplectic manifold is quantizable. Only those, whose symplectic form satisfies a certain integrality condition. For an explicit computation/to see how the Kepler problem is treated using the integrality condition, consult the following lecture notes:

[https://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~schotten/GEQ/GEQ.pdf](https://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/%7Eschotten/GEQ/GEQ.pdf)

The energy levels of the Kepler problem are explicitly treated in version 9.2. page 82,example 7.6.